# Finite groups whose Sylow 2-subroups are Klein groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I am reading part VIII of Burnside's "Notes on the Theory of Groups of Finite Order". It was published in 1895 (Proc. London Math. Soc., vol. 26, p. 325-338, 1895, Collected Papers, vol. I, p. 590-596).

Burnside first proves something that I understand (in today's language) as follows :

$\mathbf{Statement \ 1}.$ Let $G$ be a finite group whose Sylow 2-subgroups are Klein groups. Then one (and only one) of the two following cases holds :

(i) for every Sylow 2-subgroup $V$ of $G$, the three elements of order 2 of $V$ form a conjugacy class in $N_{G}(V)$, $\vert N_{G}(V) \vert$ (and thus also $\vert G \vert$) is divisible by 12 and all elements of order 2 in $G$ are conjugate in $G$;

(ii) for every Sylow 2-subgroup $V$ of $G$, the three elements of order 2 of $V$ are pairwise non-conjugate in $G$ and $N_{G}(V) = C_{G}(V)$.

I have no problem with that.

Thereafter, Burnside's goal seems to be to prove that if $G$ is simple, it is the case (i) of Statement 1 that takes place. Today, it is an easy consequence of Burnside's transfer theorem : in case (ii), we have $N_{G}(V) = C_{G}(V)$ for every Sylow 2-subgroup $V$ of $G$, thus, by Burnside's transfer theorem, $G$ cannot be simple. But Burnside doesn't use his transfer theorem here. (I presume that he had not yet stated this theorem in 1895. By the way, when and where did he publish it for the first time ? I don't find the answer on Internet.)

I must confess that I don't understand this part of Burnside's paper. He considers a group, let us say $G$, of order $N = 4m$, with $m$ odd, he assumes that the Sylow 2-subgroups of $G$ are Klein groups and, if I understand it correctly, he notes $4m_{1}$ the order of the normalizer in $G$ of a Sylow 2-subgroup of $G$. Then he says (p. 590-591 in the Collected Papers, vol. I) :

"Suppose now that this is not the case [I understand : Suppose that we are not in case (i) of Statement 1, in other words suppose that we are in case (ii) of Statement 1.], so that the group contains 3 different conjugate sets of operations of order 2 [OK]. Every operation [Burnside says "operation" where we say "element"] of order 2 is certainly self-conjugate [For an element of a group, Burnside says "self-conjugate" where we say "central"; for a subgroup, he says "self-conjugate" where we say "normal".] in a sub-group of order $2^{2}m_{1}$ [Indeed, every element $v$ of order 2 of $G$ is contained in a Sylow 2-subgroup $V$ of $G$ and, since we are in case (ii) of Statement 1, $N_{G}(V)$ centralizes $V$ and thus centralizes $v$. Recall that $2^{2}m_{1}$ is the order of $N_{G}(V)$ for every Sylow 2-subgroup $V$ of $G$.], and may be self-conjugate in a more extensive sub-group. [In other words : $N_{G}(V)$ is contained in $C_{G}(v)$ and it is possible that $C_{G}(v)$ is greater than $N_{G}(V)$.] Let, then, $S$, an operation of order 2 be self-conjugate within a group of order $2^{2}m_{1} \mu $. [I understand : let $S$ be an element of order 2 of $G$ and let $2^{2}m_{1} \mu $ be the order of $C_{G}(S)$.] An operation of this sub-group whose order is odd, and which is not contained in the sub-group of order $2^{2}m_{1}$, is permutable with $S$, and with no operation of order 2 which is not conjugate to $S$."

What is exactly the meaning of this last sentence ? Burnside says "THE sub-group of order $2^{2}m_{1}$". But $S$ can belong to several Sylow 2-subgroups of $G$. If $S$ is in a Sylow 2-subgroup $V$ of $G$ and also in another Sylow 2-subgroup $W$ of $G$, what is "THE sub-group of order $2^{2}m_{1}$" ? $N_{G}(V)$ or $N_{G}(W)$ ?

In any case, I think that the following statement is wrong :

$\mathbf{Statement \ 2}.$ (not from Burnside, and wrong). Let $G$ be a finite group whose Sylow 2-subgroups are Klein groups. Assume that case (ii) of Statement 1 holds, so that, for every Sylow 2-subgroup $V$ of $G$, the three elements of order 2 of $V$ are pairwise non-conjugate in $G$ and $N_{G}(V) = C_{G}(V)$. Let $v$ be an element of order 2 of $G$, let $V$ be a Sylow 2-subgroup of $G$ containing $v$, let $t$ be an element of odd order in $C_{G}(v)$ and assume that $t$ is not in $N_{G}(V) = C_{G}(V)$. Then all elements of order 2 in $C_{G}(t)$ are conjugate in $G$.

Here is a counterexample. Let $H$ be a nonabelian group of order 21. Then $H$ is a semidirect product $\langle x_{7} \rangle \rtimes  \langle y_{3} \rangle $, where $x_{7}$ is an element of order 7,  $y_{3}$ an element of order 3 and $y_{3} x_{7} {y_{3}}^{-1} = {x_{7}}^{2}$.

By von Dyck's theorem, or whatever, there exists one and only one automorphism $\sigma$ of H such that $\sigma (x_{7}) = {x_{7}}^{-1}$ and $\sigma (y_{3}) = y_{3}$. Clearly, $\sigma$ is of order 2 in $Aut(H)$.

Choose a Klein group $V = \{1, a, b, c\}$. Let $\tau : v \mapsto \tau_{v}$ be the homomorphism from $V$ to $Aut(H)$ such that $\tau_{1} = \tau_{a} = id_{H}, \tau_{b} = \tau_{c} =\sigma$. Put $G = H \rtimes _{\tau}V$. Clearly the Sylow 2-subgroups of $G = H \rtimes _{\tau}V$ are Klein groups. It is easy to check that

(1) $\qquad (1, a)$ is a central element of order 2 in $G = H \rtimes _{\tau}V$;

(2) $\qquad (1, b)$ is an element of order 2 in $G = H \rtimes _{\tau}V$ and it commutes with $(y_{3}, 1)$, which is an element of order 3 in $G = H \rtimes _{\tau}V$;

(3)  $\qquad (x_{7}, b)$ is an element of order 2 in $G = H \rtimes _{\tau}V$ and it doesn't commute with $(y_{3}, 1)$.

From (1), it results that $(1, a)$ is conjugate to no element of $G = H \rtimes _{\tau}V$ other than $(1, a)$ itself. Since (for example by (2) ), $G = H \rtimes _{\tau}V$ has at least one other element of order 2 than $(1, a)$, it is not true that all the elements of order 2 in $G = H \rtimes _{\tau}V$ are conjugate in $G = H \rtimes _{\tau}V$. Thus we are not in case (i) of Statement 1, thus

(4) $\qquad$ it is case (ii) of Statement 1 which holds,

Put $W = \langle (1, a), (x_{7}, b)\rangle$. In view of (1) and (3), $W$ is a Sylow 2-subgroup $W$ of $G = H \rtimes _{\tau}V$, $(y_{3}, 1)$ commutes with $(1, a)$, $(y_{3}, 1)$ is not in $C_{G}(W)$. Thus, if Statement 2 was true, all the elements of order 2 of $G = H \rtimes _{\tau}V$ commuting with $(y_{3}, 1)$ should be conjugate to eachother in $G$. It is false, since, by (1) and (2), both $(1, a)$ and $(1, b)$ are elements of order 2 commuting with $(y_{3}, 1)$, but they are not conjugate in $G$ (since $(1, a)$ is central in $G$). Thus Statement 2 is wrong.

So my question is : do you think that Burnside's proof is correct and, if it is the case, could you make it clearer ?

I will now copy the whole proof of Burnside. Maybe it can help you understand his ideas.

"Suppose now that this is not the case, so that the group contains 3 different conjugate sets of operations of order 2. Every operation of order 2 is certainly self-conjugate in a sub-group of order $2^{2}m_{1}$, and may be self-conjugate in a more extensive sub-group. Let, then, $S$, an operation of order 2 be self-conjugate within a group of order $2^{2}m_{1} \mu $. An operation of this sub-group whose order is odd, and which is not contained in the sub-group of order $2^{2}m_{1}$, is permutable with $S$, and with no operation of order 2 which is not conjugate to $S$. Hence it must form one of a set of $2r$ conjugate operations , where $r$ is odd. If now the group be represented as a permutation group, consisting of the permutations of these $2r$ operations among themselves which arise by transforming them by all the operations of the group, any operation of order 2 which is not conjugate to $S$ will give a substitution in the permutation-group, consisting in $r$ transpositions, i.e. an odd substitution, and, therefore, the group cannot be simple. Hence, the group is certainly not simple unless the maximum sub-group, which contains an operation of order 2 self-conjugately, is of order $2^{2}m_{1}$; and when this condition is satisfied every operation of order 2 is permutable with just 2 other operations of order 2, and with no more.

But, now, if $A$, $B$ are two operations of order 2 belonging to different conjugate sets, and if $(AB)^{n} = 1$, $A$, $B$ generate a dihedral group of order $2n$. If $n$ were odd, $A$ and $B$ would be conjugate, which is not the case. Hence, $n$ must be even, and then $(AB)^{\frac{1}{2}n}$ is an operation of order 2 which is permutable with $n$ distinct pairs [?] of operations of order 2. But this is in direct contradiction to what has just been proved, so that this case cannot occur. It follows that, if a group whose order is $2^{2}m$ ($m$ odd) contains 3 different conjugate sets of operations of order 2, it cannot be simple."

$\mathbf{Edit}$ (May 22, 2021). I still feel that Burnside's proof is not absolutely correct, but I think it can be fixed (without use of transfer theory), by use of Burnside's ideas.

Let $G$ be a finite simple group whose Sylow 2-subgroups are Klein groups and let us prove that all the elements of order 2 in $G$ are conjugate.

$\mathbf{Lemma \ 1.}$ Let $G$ a finite simple group, let $t$ be an element of $G$ such that the number of conjugates of $t$ in $G$ is of the form $2r$, with $r$ odd. Then, for every element $s$ of order 2 in $G$, there exists at least one G-conjugate of $t$ which commutes with $s$.

Proof. Let $Conj(t)$ denote the set of conjugates of $t$ in $G$. From the hypotheses, $Conj(t)$ has more than an element, thus the simple group $G$ is nonabelian and acts nontrivially on $Conj(t)$ by conjugation, thus the permutation $u \mapsto sus^{-1}$ is even. If $s$ commuted with no conjugate of $t$, this permutation should be the product of $r$ transpositions (with disjoint supports) and should thus be odd, contradiction.

$\mathbf{Lemma \ 2.}$ Let $G$ be a group, let $a, b$ two elements of order 2 in $G$, not conjugate with each other in $G$. Assume that $ab$ has finite order $n$. Then $\langle a, b \rangle$ is a dihedral group of order $2n$ and $n$ is even.

Proof. The fact that $\langle a, b \rangle$ is a dihedral group of order $2n$ is classical (Rotman 1999, theor. 3.32, p. 68). Assume (absurdly) that $n$ is odd. Then the order of $\langle a, b \rangle$ is even and not divisible by 4, thus the Sylow 2-subgroups of $\langle a, b \rangle$ are its subgroups of order 2, thus (Sylow) all the subgroups of order 2 of $\langle a, b \rangle$ are conjugate in $\langle a, b \rangle$, thus all the elements of order 2 of $\langle a, b \rangle$ are conjugate in $\langle a, b \rangle$, thus $a$ and $b$ are conjugate in $\langle a, b \rangle$ and thus in $G$, contradiction.

Here is another proof that $n$ is even. If $n$ was odd, say $n = 2k + 1$, we would have $(ab)^{2k+1} = 1$, $(ab)^{k} a (ab)^{-k} = b$ thus $a$ and $b$ would be conjugate, contradiction.

$\mathbf{Theorem.}$ Let $G$ a finite simple group whose Sylow 2-subgroups are Klein groups. Then all the elements of order 2 of $G$ are conjugate.

Proof. Assume first that

(hyp. 1)$\qquad $ there exists an element $t$ of $G$ such that the number of conjugates of $t$ is of the form $2r$, with $r$ odd.

Then, by Lemma 1, every element of order 2 of $G$ commutes with (at least) one conjugate of $t$. In other words,

(2)$\qquad$ every element of order 2 of $G$ is conjugate in $G$ with an element (of order 2) of $C_{G}(t)$.

On the other hand, since the order of $G$ is divisible by 4 and not by 8, it results from (1) that $\vert C_{G}(t) \vert$ is divisible by 2 and not by 4. Thus the Sylow 2-subgroups of $C_{G}(t)$ are its subgroups of order 2, thus (Sylow) the subgroups of order 2 of $C_{G}(t)$ are conjugate in $C_{G}(t)$, which amounts to say that the elements of order 2 of $C_{G}(t)$ are conjugate in $C_{G}(t)$. With (2), this proves that all the elements of order 2 of $G$ are conjugate in $G$. Thus the theorem is true in our hypothesis (1), thus we can assume that this hypothesis is not satisfied, i.e.

(3)$\qquad$ for every element $t$ of $G$, the number of conjugates of $t$ in $G$ is odd or divisible by 4.

Assume that (absurdly),

(hyp.4)$\qquad$ there exist two elements $a$ and $b$ of order 2 of $G$ which are not conjugate in $G$.

Let $n$ denote the order of $ab$. By Lemma 2, $n$ is even and $\langle a, b \rangle$ is a dihedral group of order $2n$ (and thus of order divisible by 4).

Assume that (absurdly)

(hyp. 5)$\qquad n$ is not equal to 2.

Then, since $n$ is even and $G$ has no element of order 4, $n$ is not a power of 2, thus the dihedral group $\langle a, b \rangle$ has at least one element $t$ of odd prime order $p$, In a dihedral group, every element of odd order is conjugate to its inverse, thus $t$ and $t^{-1}$ are conjugate in $\langle a, b \rangle$. A fortiori,

(6)$\qquad t$ and $t^{-1}$ are conjugate in $G$.

Let $t'$ be a conjugate of $t$ in $G$. Then $t'$ is of order $p$. Since $p$ is odd and $\neq 1$, $t'$ and $t'^{-1}$ are distinct. Moreover, in view of (6), $t'$ and $t'^{-1}$ are conjugate in $G$. Thus the conjugates of $t$ in $G$ are in even number, thus, in view of (3), the number of conjugates of $t$ in $G$ is divisible by 4. Since the order of $G$ is divisible by 4 and not by 8, this implies that

(7)$\qquad \vert C_{G}(t) \vert$ is odd.

But $t$, being of order different from 2, is in the unique cyclic subgroup $C$ of index 2 of the dihedral group $\langle a, b \rangle$. Since $C$ is abelian, $C$ centralizes $t$, thus $C_{G}(t)$ contains $C$. But the order of $C$ is $n$ and is thus even, thus $C_{G}(t) \vert$ is even, which contradicts (7). Thus our hypothesis (5) is false, thus (always in our hypothesis 4), $n = 2$, in other words the order of $ab$ is 2, which implies that $a$ and $b$ commute. Thus we have proved that

(8)$\qquad$ for all elements $a, b$ of order 2 of $G$ which are not conjugate in $G$, $a$ and $b$ commute.

If $a$ and $b$ are two such elements, then, every conjugate $b'$ of $b$ in $G$ is an element of order 2 which is not conjugate to $a$, thus the hypotheses on $a$ and $b$ in (8) are satisfied by $a$ and $b'$, thus every conjugate of $b$ commutes with $a$, thus

(9)$\qquad$ the subgroup of $G$ generated by the conjugates of $b$ is contained in $C_{G}(a)$.

But the subgroup of $G$ generated by the conjugates of $b$ is a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$, thus, since $G$ is assumed to be simple, the subgroup of $G$ generated by the conjugates of $b$ is the whole $G$, thus (9) means that $C_{G}(a) = G$, thus $a$ is central in $G$, which is impossible, since $G$ is a nonabelian simple group. Thus our hypothesis (4) is absurd, which proves the theorem.

We can conclude from this theorem that (if $G$ is a simple group whose Sylow 2-subgroups are Klein groups), then, for every Sylow 2-subgroup $V$ of $G$, the three elements of order 2 of $V$ are conjugate in $N_{G}(V)$. (Rotman 1999, Lemma 7.49, p. 196.) So, we have proved, without transfer theory, that if $G$ is a simple group whose Sylow 2-subgroups are Klein groups, then case (i) of the Statement 1 above holds.

Do you think my formulation of the proof is better than Burnside's, or do I see difficulties wherd there is none?

Comment: I haven't had time to read all of your post, but I agree that your example is a counterexample to Statement 2.

Comment: @ Derek Holt Perhaps I should have made it clear that statement 2 is not from Burnside. This is how one might be tempted to understand Burnside's problematic passage.

Comment: I am not sure whether I will find the time to read carefully what you have written in the next few days. But frankly my opinion is that it makes much more sense to learn Burnside's Transfer Theorem and use that. It is not particularly difficult and has many applications.

Comment: @ Derek Holt OK, and, parenthetically, I learned Burnside's transfer theorem, but I'm interested in understanding Burnside's ideas. Perhaps he uses (implicitly) his 1895 note in subsequent papers, so it is better to understand his 1895 note before reading the subsequent papers.